# find polynominal of degree $3$ that approximates the function

Tags: integration, polynomials, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

Question is:

> Find the polynominal of degree $3$ that approximates the function $$ h(x)= \int \frac{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}{1+3x}\,\mathrm dx$$ where $a= \dfrac14$ and $b=0$.

I have already worked out the binominal series of $$(1-4x^2)^{1/2}$$ and $$(1+3x)^{-1}$$ as that was one of my previous questions, but I'm stuck now.

Comment: What kind of approximation is required? **Any** polynomial of **any** degree can approximate **any** function. You have to be **more** specific about the approximation. What does $a=1/4$ and $b=0$ have to do with the approximation?

Comment: @aaaaaa. In your question you wrote $a=\frac14$ and $b=0$. But $a$ and $b$ are not appearing elsewhere. They are not in the integral. Are they some coefficients of the sought polunomial ? Since they are coming as a surprise I vote to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

Expand,

$$\sqrt{1-4x^2} = 1-2x^2+O(x^4), \>\>\>\>\> \frac1{1+3x} = 1-3x+9x^2+O(x^3)$$

to approximate the integrand,

$$\frac{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}{1+3x}
= (1-2x^2+O(x^4))(1-3x+9x^2+O(x^3))=1-3x+7x^2+O(x^3)$$

Then,

$$h(x)= \int \frac{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}{1+3x} \approx \int (1-3x+7x^2)dx = x-\frac32x^2 +\frac73 x^3$$

Answer (score 0):

Since you already worked the binomial expansion
$$\sqrt{1-4 x^2}=1-2 x^2-2 x^4-4 x^6+O\left(x^8\right)$$ just perform the long division by $(1+3x)$. This would give
$$\frac{\sqrt{1-4 x^2}}{1+3 x}=1-3 x+7 x^2-21 x^3+61 x^4-183 x^5+545 x^6-1635 x^7+O\left(x^8\right)$$
Integrate termwise and stop at the degree you are asked for. Do not forget the integration constant.